# RxJS: Mimic Angulars @Input() binding?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Im pretty new to Angular 8 and RxJS and stumbled upon an issue:

I make an angular app which relies heavily on an externally loaded THREE.js scene. Services handle those scenes.

So most of the time there is **No HTML Template** (only maintaining scene via js object) => **no bindings** ?

So I was thinking... is there a way to use Rxjs subjects/observables to achieve something like Input() binding?

thats what i basically want to

```
this.sub = myService.watch('window.deviceorientation')
.subscribe({next(x => { if(x) this.sub.unsubscribe; doStuff();})})
```

I want to continously check a certain object (any really), be notified as soon as it exists (or instantly if it already does). I bet there is some weird combination of RxJS Operators which can do exactly this?

(So basically its a little bit like AngularJS scope.$watch but to keep performance I'd of course clean up subscriptions.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I worked my way around this.

I created a root-level component that allows me to watch for specific changes on scope:

//HTML

```
<app-change-detector [watch]="window.anyObject" (onChange)="anyRootService.onObjectChanged($event)">
```

//TS

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-change-detector'
})
export class ChangeDetectorComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() watch: any;
  @Output() onChange = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes && changes.watch) {
      this.onChange.emit(changes.watch.currentValue);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`fromEvent`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html) rxjs creation utility to achieve the desired effect.

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

orientation$ = fromEvent(window, 'deviceorientation');

const subscription = orientation$.subscribe((event)=>{
  //do stuff
});

// when disponse is required
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: does this require an event to be emitted? actually i wanna check for an object change...